# Scalable strategy to run an executable on nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, c, server, executable

I have an `executable` that I'm using on my `nodejs` server (*on localhost in ubuntu*) to calculate some complex mathematical expressions. Recently I found that when the server gets too many calls to run the `executable`, it goes down. I'm guessing it might be a problem of `scalability` as I have only a single `executable` to serve all the calls.

I thought to use multiple copies of the `executable` but I'm not sure if it's a good approach. Please share some standard ways to approach this problem

Comment: What errors are in the log when it crashes?

Comment: Basically, my executable dumps the code which it otherwise processes correctly

Comment: Now I'm more eager to know some standard way to scale this up.